# Send message from lambda account A to an SQS of account B

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, serverless, identity-management

I need to send message from lambda account A to an SQS of another account B.

In account B, I have created the sqs like this:

```
Resources:
    SampleSqs:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: sample-sqs-service-queue.fifo
        FifoQueue: true
        VisibilityTimeout: 400
        ContentBasedDeduplication: true
```

and created the access role policy as:

```
    SqsRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: sample-sqs-Account-Role
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS:
                  - arn:aws:iam::<Account-A>:root
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess
```

I also tried adding the sqs queue as resource under statement section, but is failing at the time of deployment with the below message:

> SqsRole - Has prohibited field Resource (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument;

In account A, I am trying to acces the account B sqs SampleSqs, by importing the queue url,but i am getting access denied, code for account A:

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sts:AssumeRole
      Resource:
         - arn:aws:iam::$<AccountB>:role/sample-sqs-Account-Role
```

trying to access that sqs through its url in my code but getting access denied.

I am quite new to aws and serverless framework, Could someone please help me with what serverless code setup I require in both interface's to give Account B sqs queue's access to account A.

I tried adding the sqs queue as resource under statement section in sqsRole, but is failing at the time of deployment with the below message:

> SqsRole - Has prohibited field Resource (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument;

Comment: Is your application that's running with account A credentials actually assuming the account B sample-sqs-Account-Role to get credentials and using those credentials to access the SQS queue?

Comment: no not through credentials but just need sqs url access in account A, so that can send messages to that sqs queue of Account B.

Comment: See [Grant cross-account permissions to a role and a user name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html#grant-cross-account-permissions-to-role-and-user-name)  to provide the account A Lambda function role with permission for the account B SQS queue. (remove the IAM user part of the policy)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Amazon documentation on error: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-principal-policy/

More importantly, I do not know your exact scenario here but I would think instead of creating a whole role in account be to be assumed to access sqs, it would be easier and probably more appropriate to simply grant necessary permissions by changing the policy on sqs (resource policy).

There are very easy to understand examples directly addressing this use-case here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html

Comment: I change my code to give access to account A through QueuePolicy,

Comment: `    SampleSQSPolicy: 
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      Properties: 
        Queues: 
          - { Ref: SampleSqs }
        PolicyDocument: 
          Statement: 
            - 
              Action: 
                - "SQS:SendMessage" 
                - "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
              Effect: "Allow"
              Resource: !GetAtt SampleSqs.Arn
              Principal:
                AWS: 
                  - arn:aws:iam::AccountA:root`

Comment: But I am still unable to access this queue from account A, Could you please suggest how to setup code to access queue of Account B in account A,

Comment: Two things you need to do. 1.) account B, grant access to queue for role in account A
2) In account A, grant the role permission to send message